# Вывод в div через jquery.ajax постепенно, по мере загрузки

Tags: jquery, ajax

Задача - при `jquery.ajax-запросе` выводить результат в `div` не тогда, когда он полностью получен браузером, а по мере его загрузки. Нужно, если данные достаточно объёмные. Событие `success` или `complete` не подходят, т.к. срабатывают уже после полной загрузки данных.

Собственно, вопрос в том, есть ли вариант реализации? Деление данных на сервере на части и пулинг - не рассматриваются.

Благодаря ответам (всем спасибо!) разобрался. Решение есть, основано на использовании объекта `jqXHR`. Детали - по ссылке http://incode.pro/jquery/ajax-na-praktike-progress-bar-indikator-protsessa-zagruzki.html. Прогресс-бар меня не интересовал, т.к. было невозможно рассчитать % загрузки, а вот вывод данных возможен, если использовать свойство `target.response` объекта, возвращаемого установленным обработчиком подгрузки. По ходу загрузки нужно лишь выводить в нужный DOM-элемент тело ответа, которое имеется в `target.response`, причём целиком, не частями!. Типа так:

`$('#ResultBox').html(evt.target.response)`

Comment: Есть событие [progress](https://www.w3.org/TR/progress-events/)

Comment: вот здесь можете почитать http://incode.pro/jquery/ajax-na-praktike-progress-bar-indikator-protsessa-zagruzki.html

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 4):

С частью html - всё достаточно просто, хотя и не так безоблачно. Для прогрессбара используют или тег  (реже ), или создают кастомный из любого понравившегося html-элемента. Первые два не очень кроссбраузерны, но предусмотренный в них альтернативный текст, который можно использовать для показа процентов выполнения загрузки, немного исправляет положение. Со вторым вариантом - приходится повозится в CSS, но это не проблема для людей знающих. Мы остановимся на первом, т.к. у нас сейчас основная цель - разобраться с механизмом на JavaScript.

Итак, создадим простую форму для загрузки файла и после поля файла, разместим прогресс-бар, в котором нас интересуют два атрибута: value - текущее значение и max - максимальное значение. Так как мы будем использовать проценты, значения будут колебатся от нуля до ста. Соответственно стартовое значение (value) должно быть "0", а максимальное (max) - "100":

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post" id="my_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>
    <label for="my_file">Файл:</label>
    <input type="file" name="my_file" id="my_file">
    <progress id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

В JS пишем код $.ajax запроса и добавляем к параметрам **xhr**, в callback-функции которого, мы можем работать с объектом XMLHttpRequest, изменяя или дополняя его поведение, получать доступ его свойствам и методам, устанавливать свои обработчики событий и т.д.:

```
$(function(){
    var progressBar = $('#progressbar');
    $('#my_form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            formData = new FormData($this.get(0));
        $.ajax({
            url: $this.attr('action'),  
            type: $this.attr('method'),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            xhr: function(){
                // получаем объект XMLHttpRequest
                var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                // добавляем обработчик события progress (onprogress)
                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(evt){
                    // если известно количество байт
                    if(evt.lengthComputable) { 
                        // высчитываем процент загруженного
                        var percentComplete = Math.ceil(evt.loaded / evt.total * 100);
                        // устанавливаем значение в атрибут value тега <progress>
                        // и это же значение альтернативным текстом для браузеров, не поддерживающих <progress>
                        progressBar.val(percentComplete).text('Загружено ' + percentComplete + '%');
                    }
                }, false);
                return xhr;
            },
            success: function(json){
                if(json){
                    $this.after(json);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Что касается серверной части, то там работаем с файлом/файлами, как если бы вы их загружали обычным способом.

Готово! Теперь, чтобы протестировать на локальной машине, нужно выбрать файл побольше, иначе загрузка будет происходить практически моментально и работу прогрессбара, вы попросту не заметите. Что будет в обработчике в этом случае - не важно, главное, чтоб он был. И не забудьте перед тестированием, установить значение директивы **upload_max_filesize** чуть больше, чем загружаемый файл. Для временого изменения - это проще всего сделать в файле .htaccess, прописав строку:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M # вместо 1000 - своё значение
```

*Источник: http://incode.pro/jquery/ajax-na-praktike-progress-bar-indikator-protsessa-zagruzki.html*